# Validation check if requested value exists in another table Laravel 9

Tags: laravel

Hello i am trying to make a validation that checks the inserted values if they exist or not in other tables. This is the code i have done now:

```
$request->validate([
            'order_number' => 'required',
            'client_id' => 'required,exists:clients',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);
```

These values are inserted in a table called `order` but the client_id is taken from another table called `clients` and i want to verify if the value of `client_id` exists in the row `id` of the table `clients`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check here
[Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#specifying-a-custom-column-name)

As mentioned in laravel document you need to specify a column name, because if you don't, it will use the key in the request for the column name, so in your example, it will be the `clients` table and `client_id` column but you need to specify the column name in exists rule, it will be something like this:

```php
$request->validate([
            'order_number' => 'required',
            'client_id' => 'required|exists:clients,id',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Also, you used the wrong syntax for separating rules, after `required` you need to use a pipe(`|`) to separate your rules and use multiple validations.

Comment: thank you for your answer i already did it, still is correct i will accept it

Comment: Good to hear that, did you use the above syntax? Also, you can use the `Rule:exists()` method of the Rule facade.

Comment: yes i used the same code as you sent it i found it in the documentation of `Laravel`